# ClientConfiguration.connectedTo sets wrong connection

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have this configuration

```
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        HgElasticsearchProperties properties = appPropertiesService.getElasticsearchProperties();

        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("https://localhost:443")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}
```

And I have this ClientConfiguration as a result:

[image]

How can I set the correct elastic connection up? (`"https://localhost:443`")

Answer (score 1):

setup for secure connection would be:

```
.connectedTo("localhost").useSsl()
```

Edit:

"localhost:443", the port needs to be defined here as well

Comment: Can I connect to 2 servers `https://localhost:443` and `http://localhost:9200` ?

Comment: no. The Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient uses the same HttpClientConfiguration for the connections to the different hosts of a cluster. And ssl setup is part of this configuration

Comment: But how can I set `useSsl()` dynamically? We have not setters and useSsl(true/false) methods. It is strange builder