# Spring boot + elasticsearch wrong default port

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000769/clientconfiguration-connectedto-sets-wrong-connection) question about spring boot and elasticsearch.

I have this config:

```
@Bean
@Override
public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration
            = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo("foo.es.amazonaws.com")
            .usingSsl()
            .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
}
```

But I get this config(port: 9200 instead of 443)

[image]

I added `usingSsl()` and expected 443 port. How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

```
.connectedTo("foo.es.amazonaws.com:443")
```

`useSsl()` activates SSL on the defined connection. This must not be necessarily 443.

Comment: I have just read the documentation. It is true. I thought that using `useSsl()` means default 443 port too. It is wrong. but it makes sense, are you agree?